# Is there a lightweight Python module to load pre-fitted ML modules and perform prediction?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, raspberry-pi2

I am implementing a Machine Learning module that should run in a Raspberry Pi that at the moment is shared among different services.
My idea is to store in the device only the code in charge of retrieving the inputs of the ML module and performing the prediction, together with the file containing the Neural Network model already fitted using Keras. 
In other words, I would like to avoid to install all the Keras/Tensorflow packages and dependencies if my purpose is only to perform the prediction on a trained model, and not to train a new model.
Is there a way to do that? Are there any lightweight libraries that allow to load the model of a Neural Network (with all the weights and biases settings) and perform a prediction, given the inputs?

What I am able to do now is to load in the Raspberry Pi a ".h5" file containing the model, weights and biases, but still I have to declare the building function of the model through Keras.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

def NN_model():
'''
Definition of the Neural Network model
'''
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(7, input_dim=6, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(15, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(24, kernel_initializer='normal'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
return model

'''
Load NN model and use it to predict the radiation values
for the next 24 hours, hour by hour
'''
regr = KerasRegressor(build_fn=NN_model, epochs=1000, batch_size=5, verbose=0)
regr.model = load_model('saved_model.h5')
pred=regr.predict(input_row)
```

Since a fitted Neural Network is just a matter of weights and biases (and activation functions), I would expect that, once these parameters are determined, I wouldn't need the whole Tensforflow and Keras environment to map an output to the inputs I give to the NN.

What I would like to have is just something like:

```
import lightweight_module as lm
regression_model = lm.load_model('saved_model.h5')
prediction=regression_model.predict(inputs)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide some code to show you tried

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, prune your neural network while retaining the same accuracy. It removes all the unwanted connections between different neurons that does not learn anything significant. It not only reduces complexity of your NN, also drastically reduces the storage space required & also reduces the inference time. In Keras I don't know of any such module (though I think people have made their own version), but modules like pytorch & caffe have some implementation of AlexNets & VGGNets they can reduce the size of your NN model by even 49x times. You can find one such implementation here.

https://github.com/felzek/AlexNet-A-Practical-Implementation/blob/master/testModel.py